# Generate normal distribution of numbers that are multiples of 5 with in a specified range

Tags: r

I want to generate 599 numbers (with repeats) between 0 and 100 with specified mean and sd, the generated numbers should all be multiples of 5. A pseudo code can be

`df$Murphy_task_strategy<-rnorm(mean=57, sd= 25.30, n=599,by=5, min=0, max=100)`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't strictly be a normal distribution but I'm assuming you're mainly looking for something that looks approximately bell shaped when taking a histogram.

```
rdiscnorm <- function(n, mean, sd, min = 0, max = 100, by = 5){
    # generate the possible values we can take on
    vals <- seq(from = min, to = max, by = by)
    # use dnorm to get the density at each of those points
    unnormed_probabilities <- dnorm(vals, mean = mean, sd = sd)
    # normalize so that the probabilities sum to 1
    #   - this isn't strictly necessary because we use sample
    #     but it makes sense when thinking about the process
    ps <- unnormed_probabilities/sum(unnormed_probabilities)
    
    # Take a sample with replacement of the vals
    # using the generated probabilities
    output <- sample(vals, size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = ps)
    return(output)
}

out <- rdiscnorm(599, 57, 25.30)

df$Murphy_task_strategy <- out
```